# Nginx forward UDP port to OpenVPN running on same machine

Tags: nginx, vpn, openvpn

I have a web server for hobby project running behind Nginx (listen to tcp port 443)

On the same server, I installed OpenVPN server (listen to udp port 1194). And it's working properly with my home wifi.

However, a lot of public wifi is blocking port 1194, so I want to have the Nginx listen on UDP port 443 then forward to OpenVPN on port 1194.

Here is my nginx config, I have open all the necessary firewall but it's not successful.

```
stream{
    upstream vpn_backend{
        server localhost:1194;
    }
    server{
        listen 443 udp;
        proxy_pass vpn_backend;
        proxy_responses 0;
    }
}
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: I would bind OpenVPN directly to 443 UDP. Why do you want to involve Nginx in the setup?

Comment: Because OpenVPN does not work on 443/UDP